# how to import a module in django html?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a django blog. i need to use enchant to check if the text in the blog post is english, then use the api in text error correction.

I installed the api on the virtual envieronement of the django blog

> pip install pyenchant

project, and included it on the installed apps, but in the blog base.html, i tried to load it and use it's fucntions to check whether the post title is in english or not, but i did nothing. How to solve this?
here is my html code:

```
{% load enchant %}

{% dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_US") %}
<p>{% dictionary.check(post.title) %}</p>
```

There is no errors when i run the server, but there is nothing on the html page.
Note: according to the API, it's supposed to be True of False in a paragraph tag. "i tested it in the python shell."

Comment: what tutorial are you following for that where it is said to load tag like that?

Comment: @Exprator I did not find a tuturoial that explain similar thing, but i thought it could be used like the {% load humanize %} in this documentation. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/

Comment: humanize is different and pyenchant, the thing what you are trying to achieve to that in the view and after clearing it send it to the template as pyenchat will not work in html file

Comment: You have to create a custom template tag. You can't do this like that.
See my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that like this. **Follow me :)**

There **isn't template tag existing with pyenchant** to work with django (what i learn from the doc).
Your code **`dictionary = enchant.Dict("en_US")` is ok on the django back-end**, but it don't fit the django template as well.

So to achieve to do that, you can **create a custom template tag** to make the join between your python code and template language.

You can do as follow, it works :

**Tree** :

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/pyenchant_tags.py
```

The **templatetags/pyenchant_tags.py file**:

```
import enchant
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def please_enchant_my_string(language, string):
    d = enchant.Dict(language)
    return d.check(string)
```

The **template part**, with our tag call:

```
{% load pyenchant_tags %}

<div>
    {% please_enchant_my_string 'en_US' post.title %}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.it works, but it gave me an error on passing 'en_US', so i decided to make the function accept one parameter only "string" and wrote defined the 'en_US' inside the function and it worked for me. 
`def please_enchant_my_string(string):
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    return d.check(string)`

Comment: @Hathout
Fine :)
weird it didn't work !

Yes what you did work, but in the long run (eg. if you want to translate your django application), it's better to feed it with a param. OR you can define some language constants in your settings.py file, set up the current to "en_US" if not yet done and call the current language from your template tag. In conclusion you will be able to switch easily your language.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) @Akshay